# undefined symbols := operator in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there any way to enhance and get information about the `:=` operator?

How can I use this operator and what is the benefit? I tried to search engines but found nothing.

have a look:

```
xlssheat = Nothing
xlsfile.Close(SaveChanges := True)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a lot on the msdn site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51wfzyw0.aspx

In short the operator is used to supply values for an argument based on the name of the argument rather than the position of the argument in the arguments list.

Comment: Answers are suppossed to include, well answers. Not link to external ressources that might provide the answer. This is for several reasons one of them being. Links have a tendency to become dysfunc over time resulting in the answer no longer being available

Comment: @RuneFS you are quite right and I will expand out the answer in future.  As this is already flagged as a dupe I'll leave it be.